# How to define individual link style on react-d3-tree

Tags: css, d3.js, hyperlink, tree

I need to define link style between each node differently. Now I have my treedata defined as below, while the link style is not working. Could anyone help on this?

```
const myTreeData = [
  {

    name: 'Top Level',
    nodeSvgShape: {
         shape: 'circle',
         shapeProps:{r:30,fill:"red"}
    },
    Styles:{
          links: {
                  fill:"none",
                  stroke: "#000",
                  strokeWidth: "2px",
                  strokeDasharray:"2,2"
                },
     }
    children: [
      {
        name: 'Level 2: A',
        nodeSvgShape: {
             shape: 'circle',
             shapeProps:{r:30,fill:”green”}
        },
        Styles:{
            links: {
                  fill:"none",
                  stroke: "#222",
                  strokeWidth: "2px",
                  strokeDasharray:"2,2"
                },
        }
      },
      {
        name: 'Level 2: B',
        nodeSvgShape: {
             shape: 'circle',
             shapeProps:{r:30,fill:”yellowfins”}
        },
        Styles:{
          links: {
                  fill:"none",
                  stroke: "#000",
                  strokeWidth: "2px",
                  strokeDasharray:"2,2"
                },
        }
      },
    ],
  },
];
```

nodeSvgShape works so each node shows defined color, but link styles does not work.

Comment: Did you got the solution for this @meggie111?

Answer (score 0):

hmmm, have you tried using lowercase s for styles. This works for me on the main tree object (I'm not sure about individial):

```
 <Tree
      data={debugData}
     // collapsible={false}
      translate={this.state.translate}
      scaleExtent={{ min: 1, max: 3 }}
      allowForeignObjects
     // pathFunc="elbow"
      orientation="vertical"
      nodeSvgShape={{ shape: "none" }}
      nodeSize={{ x: 200, y: this.yClearance }}
      onClick={e => this.click(e)}
      onMouseOver={e => this.over(e)}
      styles={{
        links: {
             
              stroke: 'red',
              strokeWidth: "2px",
            },
     }}
```

Comment: This will work for full chart, but not work for specific node.